# Scope visibility of anonymous functions

Tags: haskell, lambda, scope, anonymous-function

I'm currently reading "Real World Haskell" and is confused by one function implemented there:

```
parseP5_take2 :: L.ByteString -> Maybe (Greymap, L.ByteString)
parseP5_take2 s =
    matchHeader (L8.pack "P5") s       >>?
    \s -> skipSpace ((), s)           >>?
    (getNat . snd)                    >>?
    skipSpace                         >>?
    \(width, s) ->   getNat s         >>?
    skipSpace                         >>?
    \(height, s) ->  getNat s         >>?
    \(maxGrey, s) -> getBytes 1 s     >>?
    (getBytes (width * height) . snd) >>?
    \(bitmap, s) -> Just (Greymap width height maxGrey bitmap, s)
```

What I cannot get is how the `width`, `height` and others have leaked from the anonymous function scope and became available in the latest expression.

The exact place in RWH: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/code-case-study-parsing-a-binary-data-format.html#id624895

Simplified own piece of code fails as I expect:

```
Prelude> (\x -> x) 5 + (\y -> x) 6

<interactive>:4:22: Not in scope: `x'
```

So why does it work in their code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You’re probably reading it like this:

```
(\(width, s) -> getNat s) >>? (\(height, s) -> getNat s) >>? ...
```

In that case, you’d be right; you can’t access things that are out of scope like that. But it’s actually like this:

```
(\(width, s) -> ((getNat s) >>? (\(height, s) -> (getNat s) >>? (...))))
```

In words, those expressions aren’t independent; it’s actually nested, although their indentation doesn’t show it clearly, and you certainly can access things from an outer scope.

To see why, consider that `\x -> x + 5` is interpreted as `\x -> (x + 5)` rather than `(\x -> x) + 5`. The `\` is very greedy in consuming its lambda body, and won’t stop at the `+`, just as it won’t stop at the `>>?`.

Comment: But isn't `>>?` left associative? They even explain it as " In other words, `a >>? b >>? c` will be evaluated from left to right, as `(a >>? b) >>? c`)"

Comment: `>>?` is left-associative, but ``\`` is greedy and will consume as much as it can; it won’t stop when it approaches another `>>?`.

Answer (score 10):

Each lambda expression [extends as far to the right as possible](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html).

> The grammar is ambiguous regarding the extent of lambda abstractions,
>   let expressions, and conditionals. The ambiguity is resolved by the
>   meta-rule that each of these constructs extends as far to the right as
>   possible.

The expressions that use `width` and `height` do have those in scope, because they are inside the lambda that introduced them.